# Tweetsharp - Oauthaccestoken overflowexception

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I've been stuck for a while on the following problem when I debug the following code:

```
        TwitterService service = new TwitterService("_consumerkey", "_consumersecret");

        OAuthRequestToken requestToken = service.GetRequestToken();

        Uri uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
        Process.Start(uri.ToString());

        Console.Write("Verificatiecode? ");
        string verifier = Console.ReadLine();
        OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);

        service.AuthenticateWith(access.Token, access.TokenSecret);

        TwitterUser twitterUser = service.GetUserProfile(new GetUserProfileOptions());

        ListFriendsOptions friends_options = new ListFriendsOptions();
        friends_options.UserId = twitterUser.Id;
        friends_options.Cursor = -1;

        var friends = service.ListFriends(friends_options);

        do
        {
            if (friends_options.Cursor != null)
            {
                foreach (var friend in friends) {Console.WriteLine(friend.ScreenName);}
                friends_options.Cursor = friends.NextCursor;
            }

        } while (friends_options.Cursor != null);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

I always get an overflow exception after filling in the verification code here:

```
        OAuthAccessToken access = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any further progress on this, I have similar code working in my app but only some of the time it fails - other time it's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source, it seems like the problem is when it tries to return the results inside `GetAccessToken`:

```
 return new OAuthAccessToken()
  {
    Token = nameValueCollection["oauth_token"] ?? "?",
    TokenSecret = nameValueCollection["oauth_token_secret"] ?? "?",
    //this is the only place a conversion to int is occurring that I've found
    UserId = Convert.ToInt32(nameValueCollection["user_id"] ?? "0"),
    ScreenName = nameValueCollection["screen_name"] ?? "?"
  };
```

Looking on Github, it seems [this update](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/commit/c032df4339672de5993de5c9f18ff9730caf1c07) might solve the problem.

Comment: I am getting the same error, as I get latest TweetSharp library from Nuget

Answer (score 2):

Download the last version of TweetSharp, old version has user_id as Int32, but new version as Int64 https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Twitter introduced 64bit user ids a while back.

Older Twitter accounts still have the 32-bit Ids and TweetSharp works just fine with them. But if you opened an account recently you already might have a 64 bit ID and Tweet Sharp fails.

I fixed the problem by getting the tweetsharp-unofficial package from NuGet.